# Backfilling data on missing time intervals (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with 15min intervals, yet it is missing many values between 19:00 and 21:00. I would like to complete it with values from the nearest available row from the same day. As example:

See the table attached:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBd8m.png)

The Date column is currently my index column.

Tried resampling, yet it resulted in error "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'"

First column is in datetime format, duplicates are already dropped.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df2=(df.set_index('Date' )
     .apply(lambda x: x.resample('15min').ffill().bfill()  )
     .reset_index() ) 
df2
```

```
Date    Close
0   2019-02-26 19:15:00     175.095
1   2019-02-26 19:30:00     175.360
2   2019-02-26 19:45:00     175.555
3   2019-02-26 20:00:00     175.505
4   2019-02-26 20:15:00     175.240
...     ...     ...
93  2019-02-27 18:30:00     175.030
94  2019-02-27 18:45:00     175.030
95  2019-02-27 19:00:00     174.470
96  2019-02-27 19:15:00     173.800
97  2019-02-27 19:30:00     174.140
```